# Ng-Repeat not displaying correct results

Tags: angularjs

```
 <p ng-repeat="(key,value) in selectedLoanApplicationDetails track by key">
  {{key}}--- {{value}}
 </p>
```

```js
$scope.selectedLoanApplicationDetails = {
     "Terms AND Conditions Accepted":"No",
     "LoanId":"a2NZ0000002CfmxMAC",
     "Loan Type":"INSTALLMENT",
     "Loan Status":"",
     "Loan Application Name":"Loan-0005",
     "Active":"Yes"
}
```

In above the result coming in is 
0--- [
1--- {
2--- "
3--- T
4--- e
5--- r
6--- m
7--- s
8---
9--- A
10--- N
11--- D
12---
13--- C

I tried using track by $index but same output. Can someone help. Thanks

Comment: Works as expected in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/lrRO9mTcIba36PqOshsw?p=preview).

Comment: Actually there was a problem as in javascript it was not a json object type but a string which was creating a problem to render the results. Once I did JSON.parse on the string it gave me correct results. thanks